# Flex - how to get a list of Air Window titles that are currently open (or check for a specific window title)?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

In my Flex (Flash Builder 4.6) application, I am opening an Adobe AIR "Window" object, via:

myWindowObject = new MyWindow();   // this is a ""
myWindowObject.title="custom window title here";
myWindowObject.open;

In the application, the user may open several windows.   I need to prevent the user from opening the same window twice.   So I either need an ability to check for the existence of a window currently open with a specific title, OR get a list of all the open windows, and then I could look at that list to see if it's already open.

How can I get a list of the window titles, or check for a window with a specific title?

Comment: we use a WindowManager class that we wrote that adds, removes and manages all windows in a central class.  So you can call things like manager.addWindow(myWindow)  and if(manager.hasWindow(WindowClass)). This pattern makes it really clean to do things like what you want :)

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to sample code / class, or is that something you created (or can share)?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm using RobotLegs framework and we created really in-depth code to manage mediator mappings, window groups, parent / child / sibling relationships etc.  But if you make a singleton and then have an addWindow method that creates and adds the window... then stores a reference to that window in a dictionary or Vector, then you can later call a method hasWindow(WindowClass) and loop through the open window references and return true or false if the class matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Air framework provides an Array of all opened windows:

`FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows;`

You can iterate through these and check the title of each and do with it as you wish.